# How can I block select in Geany?

Tags: textselection, geany

I often need to select a block of text, like a leading character that occurs on many lines. LibreOffice has block selection. How can I do this in Geany?

For example, I want to remove the pipe and the space at the beginning of each line:

```
| Create another 'Login Role' for the 'auth' user:
| Role name: auth
| Password: auth
| Role privileges: Create database objects
```

Comment: Alt + Shift + (Drag Mouse).

Comment: @tod: It can be done [without the mouse](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/12/31/block-column-mode-in-text-editors-geany-visual-studio-ultraedit-notepad-and-visual-studio-code-and-vim/): Shift + Alt + arrow keys

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's called "column mode editing".  Look here:

- http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#column-mode-editing-rectangular-selections

> **Column mode editing (rectangular selections)**
>
> There is basic support for column mode editing. To use it, create a
> rectangular selection by holding down the Control and Shift keys (or
> Alt and Shift on Windows) while selecting some text. Once a
> rectangular selection exists you can start editing the text within
> this selection and the modifications will be done for every line in
> the selection.
>
> It is also possible to create a zero-column selection - this is useful
> to insert text on multiple lines.

---

Peter Mortensen has documented how to configure this on Lubuntu (for LXQt):

> https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/03/29/using-geany/#Column_mode_blues
>
> On Lubuntu, the keyboard shortcuts for selecting a rectangular area of
> text (“column mode” in UltraEdit) do not work, because they conflict
> with four default keyboard shortcuts in the window manager (LXDE?
> Openbox?), `Shift + Alt + arrow up`, `Shift + Alt + arrow down`,
> `Shift + Alt + arrow left`, and `Shift + Alt + arrow right`.
>
> Disable the window manager keyboard shortcuts by editing file
> `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` near “S-A-Up”, “S-A-Down”,
> “S-A-Left”, and “S-A-Right”. For example, change “S-A-Up” to
> “S-A-Up99”, “S-A-Down” to “S-A-Down99”, “S-A-Left” to “S-A-Left99”,
> and “S-A-Right” to “S-A-Right99”, respectively. And add an XML comment
> as to why and document the original values (so they can more easily be
> reverted). Edit and update (without a restart required):
>
> ```
> vi ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
> openbox --reconfigure
> ```
>
> It was tested with Lubuntu 18.04 (32 bit).

Comment: I have documented how to do [the configuration changes for Lubuntu](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/03/29/using-geany/#Column_mode_blues) (for [LXQt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXQt)).

Answer (score 11):

In [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) the following works for me: press only the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and select by the mouse (***not*** both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys, as described in the manual).

Answer (score 6):

In [Ubuntu MATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE) (Geany 1.25) I can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then mark the text using arrow keys.

Answer (score 4):

I think, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + mouse(!). It's working correct on Ubuntu with Geany 1.23.1. Please use the mouse, not the arrow keys.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Mouse on [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 7.3.

Answer (score 0):

For me the key shortcuts are different. After installing the *[Extra Selection](https://plugins.geany.org/geanyextrasel.html)* Geany plugin, I can use:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (and then use the up, down, etc. arrow keys to move the cursor; edit the text; and then repeat <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to go back to 'normal' edit mode).

More information is [here](https://plugins.geany.org/geanyextrasel.html).

(I use [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) with [Xubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu) 16.04.4 LTS (Windows 10 host).)